# 2 new monitors and I can get only one to display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have a brand new Dell 8930 and new monitor.  I have a Samsung curved screen.  I use it for photography so I really like the two screens for that and work.  Problem is there is only one HDMI/DVI port on each.  Both have VGAs.  I have connected the curved monitor to the PC and checked that the new monitor works as well. I then connected the 2 monitors via VGA.  Nada.  They don't see each other and therefore I cannot extend my screen.  Should I get a VGA to HDMI converter to get them to work or did I just waste $$ on a new monitor? Help!

Comment: By "extend your screen", are you envisioning different content on each monitor?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot connect the Monitor/TV in this way. Most TV's are equipped with VGA-in, HDMI-in ports, but these are meant for input, not output. In order to connect to multiple monitors, you need to have all input coming from your PC. If your PC has a VGA port, connect your PC to one monitor with VGA, then connect your other monitor/TV to your PC with HDMI. If you do not have VGA on your PC, then consider purchasing an HDMI splitter, that allows you too output with two cables even if you have only one port.